i18n.locale not update in middleware after navigateTo() to another lang - nuxt 3
The Middleware has a function that if the user's chosen language is different from the current language, it is changed. But the problem is that after the user switches to the intended path or URL (which is in another language), i18n.locale remains the same as its first value before the path or URL was changed.
languages:
Arabic ar - (default)
English en
PAGE :
test.vue
PATH :
/test
/en/test
Middleware :
Let me assume that there is a variable (depending on the user's language), but for simplicity I will use string :
const userLangSelect = 'ar';

 export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to) => {
  const userLangSelect = 'ar'; // Get it from the user, but for simplicity I chose string
  const nuxt = useNuxtApp();
  const localePath = useLocalePath();
  const i18n = nuxt.$i18n;

  if(i18n.locale.value !== userLangSelect) {
   console.log(to.fullPath,i18n.locale.value);
   return navigateTo(localePath(to.fullPath, userLangSelect)) // to path same lang user;
  }
 });

When you enter /en/test, you will be directed to /test, Here it will enter an infinite loop, because the value of i18n.locale.value has not changed, But the user was directed to /test.
console.log :

Knowing that when you enter the path /test manually (meaning through the browser, you typed the path /test and pressed enter) the value of i18n.locale.value becomes ar

I know a solution that works, but I don't know. I think there is a better solution,
export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware(async (to) => {
  const userLangSelect = 'ar';
  const nuxt = useNuxtApp();
  const localePath = useLocalePath();
  const i18n = nuxt.$i18n;
  
  if(i18n.locale.value !== userLangSelect) {
   console.log(to.fullPath,i18n.locale.value);
   i18n.setLocale(userLangSelect); // <======
   return navigateTo(localePath(to.fullPath, userLangSelect)) 
  }
});

